# Counting Variables in R with 3 columns

Tags: r, dplyr, count, tidyverse

I have been working on this but nothing seems to work. I have this dataset that is approximately 10k.

After cleaning the data. I want to count the products sold (There are more than 30 types that are repetitive) to see which one is sold the most and flagging the top 10. However, I would want to include the price of one unit next to the (n) column. For example, Apple was sold 1111 times I want $1 next to the count

| Product_name | Sold | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 1.00 |
| Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| Apple | 1 | 1.00 |
| Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| Apple | 1 | 1.00 |
| Orange | 1 | 2.00 |

Usning: df %>% count(Product_name)
give this:

| Product_Name | n |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1111 |
| Orange | 2222 |

and I want to do this

| Product_name | n | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1111 | 1.00 |
| Orange | 2222 | 2.00 |

In my data, I have something similar to this example and I have probably 30 different product_name
I would really appreciate the help.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the price does not vary for a particular product you could just use `Price = first(Price)` within the summarise statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using native `aggregate()` function.

```
Product_name <- c("Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Orange")
Sold <- c(1,2,1,1,1)
Price <- c(1,1,2,1,2)

df <- data.frame(Product_name, Sold, Price)

new_df <- aggregate(Sold ~ Product_name + Price, data = df, sum)
```

Resulting in:

```
Product_name Price Sold
Apple     1    4
Orange     2    2
```